# Use the ThinkVantage button on linux

Tags: linux, xmonad, thinkpad

How can I use the thinkvantage button of a thinkpad on linux? I tried xev and also acpi_listen to get the correct key-event. But both doesn't print anyting.

**Edit**

I want to make this work under xmonad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gnome you can go to Settings -> Keyboard and edit/add keyboard shortcuts that use the ThinkVantage key.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it under gnome and it works great. However I am actually using xmonad as window manager, so this solution doesn't work for my setup.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Don't know how to help there.

Comment: The point is how can gnome use that key, if xev and acpi_listen doesn't output anything.

Comment: Oh, you may have a hardware issue then. I see keycode 156 in `xev` when pressing my ThinkVantage button on my Lenovo X220.

Comment: Hm. Now it works. I don't know what I did wrong.